# Why don't askers share solutions after they find them?

Tags: discussion

I've read a question I had direct interest in, someone asked a question, accepted an answer which was vague in my opinion and probably in their opinion as well because the asker commented : "nevermind, I figured it out by myself" without sharing the solution. As an outsider I felt frustrated like watching a movie and not being able to see the end to say so.

I am new here and I would like to know if the asker is required to update the members who chose to help what was the working solution . Is it about sharing knowledge and solutions or simply a direct help/support for the asker only who minds his own business once he figures out by himself. In my opinion, their solution could serve others and duplicated questions would be avoided.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> if the asker is required to update the members who chose to help what was the working solution

Ideally, they should of course do this. Considerate askers usually do it.

However, there is no way to force an asker to tell the community what worked for them. If an asker is just about grabbing the answer that worked for them, and doesn't care about the community, there's nothing we can do.

Either way - if you witness something like this happening, feel free to add a comment asking the asker to clarify what worked for them. Sometimes, there will be a response. But don't be too disappointed if there isn't.

Comment: Ideally, they should . I guess this is it... Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

People are not "required" to provide an answer to their own question - and even if they were, how would this be enforced?

You can add a comment to the question asking the questioner to share the answer.

Comment: Looks like the three of us had the same thoughts.  Upvote to you for being first :P

Comment: I did but it was deleted, the mod explained I couldnt post yet because I was new so it is okay. So, me 4.

Comment: @Ingrid You need 50 rep to post a comment.  Answer posts should always be answers, not comments!  It doesn't take long to get 50 rep though :)

Comment: Matthew, I admit I didn't know the difference between comment and answer 2 days ago. I didn't even know why it was deleted. But I understand how things work now, so I'm ok with this. I was just dissapointed that people don't return to share, that's selfish to me.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to know if the asker is required to update the members who chose to help what was the working solution

No.  There is no possible way to enforce this.

However, users are encouraged to post their own answer in the case where they solve their own problem.  If it turns out they made a silly mistake and the post was nonsense, they can leave a comment explaining and flag the question for closure as Too Localized.